# CSS Animation Issue - Button Animation

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, sass

I have the following code:

```js
var basicTimeline = anime.timeline({
  autoplay: false,
});

var pathEls = $(".check");
for (var i = 0; i < pathEls.length; i++) {
  var pathEl = pathEls[i];
  var offset = anime.setDashoffset(pathEl);
  pathEl.setAttribute("stroke-dashoffset", offset);
}

basicTimeline
  .add({
    targets: ".text",
    duration: 1,
    opacity: "0"
  })
  .add({
    targets: ".button",
    duration: 1300,
    height: 20,
    width: 81,
    backgroundColor: "#717F7E",
    border: "0",
    zIndex: 0,
    borderRadius: 100
  })
  .add({
    targets: ".progress-bar",
    duration: 2000,
    width: 81,
    easing: "linear"
  })
  .add({
    targets: ".button",
    width: 0,
    duration: 1
  })
  .add({
    targets: ".progress-bar",
    width: 40,
    height: 39,
    delay: 500,
    duration: 750,
    borderRadius: 80,
    backgroundColor: "#71DFBE",
    left: 20
  })
  .add({
    targets: pathEl,
    strokeDashoffset: [offset, 0],
    duration: 200,
    easing: "easeInOutSine"
  });


$(".button").click(playButtonAnim);

$(".text").click(playButtonAnim);

function playButtonAnim() {
  basicTimeline.play();
}

//error animation
const form = document.forms.myform;
form.onsubmit = e => {
  e.preventDefault()
  let data = Object.fromEntries(new FormData(form).entries())

  console.log(data)

  let validationOK = true
  for (let entrie in data) {
    if (!form[entrie].checkValidity()) {
      validationOK = false
      form[entrie].classList.add('shakingErr')
      setTimeout(() => {
        form[entrie].classList.remove('shakingErr')
      }, 820)
    }
  }
  if (validationOK) {
    fetch(form.action, {
        method: form.method,
        body: JSON.stringify(data),
        headers: {
          Accept: 'application/json'
        }
      })
      .finally(() => {
        window.location = "thankyou.html"
      })
  }
}
```

```css
/* Contact Form */

input[type=text],
[type=email],
select,
textarea {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 12px;
  border: 1px solid #555;
  margin-top: 6px;
  margin-bottom: 16px;
  resize: vertical;
}

input[type="text"]:focus,
input[type="email"]:focus,
#subject:focus {
  background: var(--bgFormElsFocus);
  transform: scale(1.02);
  transition: transform 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

.contactform {
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 50px;
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
  padding: 5px;
  z-index: 2;
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-bottom: auto;
  margin-top: 1%;
  width: 100%;
  animation-name: gradient;
  animation-duration: 3s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

.contactform:hover {
  animation-name: gradient;
  animation-duration: 15s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

.column {
  float: center;
  width: 50%;
  margin-top: 6px;
  padding: 20px;
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .column,
  input[type=submit] {
    width: auto;
    margin-top: 0;
  }
}

.shakingErr {
  border-color: red;
  animation: shake 0.82s forwards;
}

@keyframes shake {
  10%,
  90% {
    transform: translate3d(-1px, 0, 0);
  }
  20%,
  80% {
    transform: translate3d(2px, 0, 0);
  }
  30%,
  50%,
  70% {
    transform: translate3d(-4px, 0, 0);
  }
  40%,
  60% {
    transform: translate3d(4px, 0, 0);
  }
}


/* fancy button styles */

.buttonWrapper {
  height: 39px;
  width: 81px;
  position: relative;
}

.button {
  background: #2B2D2F;
  height: 39px;
  width: 81px;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  left: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 4px;
  z-index: 10;
}

.text {
  font: .8rem/1 poppins;
  color: #71DFBE;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-52%);
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.progress-bar {
  position: absolute;
  height: 20px;
  width: 0;
  left: 40px;
  top: 50%;
  border-radius: 200px;
  transform: translateY(-50%) translateX(-50%);
  background: black;
}

svg {
  width: 15px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 20px;
  transform: translateY(-50%) translateX(-8px);
}

.check {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #FFFFFF;
  stroke-width: 3;
  stroke-linecap: round;
  stroke-linejoin: round;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>replit</title>
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:600" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:600" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animejs/2.0.2/anime.js">
  </script>

</head>

<body>
  <!-- start contact section -->
  <section id="contact">
    <div class="container" data-aos="fade-up">
      <div class="contactform">
        <div style="text-align:center">
          <div class="section-title">
            <h2><br />Get In Touch</h2>
          </div>
          <p>Feel Free To Reach Out To Me Through This Form! </p>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="column">
            <form name="myform" action="https://formspree.io/f/xrg123232jbqpq" id="my-form" method="POST" novalidate>
              <label for="firstname">First Name</label>
              <input type="text" id="first name" name="firstname" placeholder="Your First Name.." required>
              <label for="lastname">Last Name</label>
              <input type="text" id="lastname" name="lastname" placeholder="Your Last Name.." required>
              <label for="email">Email:</label>
              <input type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Your Email.." required>
              <label for="subject">Subject</label>
              <textarea id="subject" name="subject" placeholder="Lets Collaborate.." style="height:170px" required></textarea>
              <!-- <input type="submit" value="Submit"> -->
              <div class='buttonWrapper'>
                <div class="button">
                  <div class="text">Submit</div>
                </div>
                <div class="progress-bar"></div>
                <svg x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 25 30" style="enable-background:new 0 0 25 30;">
                  <path class="check" class="st0" d="M2,19.2C5.9,23.6,9.4,28,9.4,28L23,2" />
                </svg>
              </div>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

**The only problem I'm facing is that even though I have error animation code in the JS that calls in the `shakingErr` class from CSS, the animation seems to be not working when the user clicks submit with empty/wrong fields.** How can I make it so that when the user clicks the submit button, the contact form has a shaking error button.

**Notice that when you click the submit button, there is also an animation that plays on the button?** I would not like that animation to play when the user clicks submit button on empty fields. I would only like the animation to play once the user has filled all the information in the input fields.

Any suggestions?

### EXPECTED OUTPUT

https://watch.screencastify.com/v/D2VXp3493XZXl3Lmh7yR

As you can see, whenever the user tries to click submit button on empty/wrong fields (Email) then the error animation plays. Also, the button animation should not play when the user clicks the submit button on empty/wrong fields. It should play once the fields are filled and are right.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I suggest changing the HTML of submit button to something like this for a semantic reason.

```
<button class="button" type="submit">
   <div class="text">Submit</div>
</button>
```

Then, what happens after the user clicks on the submit button will be considered as:

```
$(".button").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  let validationOK = true;
  
  // validate data
  const form = document.forms.myform;
    let data = Object.fromEntries(new FormData(form).entries())
    for (let entrie in data) {
      if (!form[entrie].checkValidity()) {
        validationOK = false;

        // error animation
        form[entrie].classList.add('shakingErr')
        setTimeout(() => {
          form[entrie].classList.remove('shakingErr')
        }, 820)
      }
    }
    
  if (validationOK) {
    basicTimeline.play();

    // your submit action
  }
});
```

```js
var basicTimeline = anime.timeline({
  autoplay: false,
});

var pathEls = $(".check");
for (var i = 0; i < pathEls.length; i++) {
  var pathEl = pathEls[i];
  var offset = anime.setDashoffset(pathEl);
  pathEl.setAttribute("stroke-dashoffset", offset);
}

basicTimeline
  .add({
    targets: ".text",
    duration: 1,
    opacity: "0"
  })
  .add({
    targets: ".button",
    duration: 1300,
    height: 20,
    width: 81,
    backgroundColor: "#717F7E",
    border: "0",
    zIndex: 0,
    borderRadius: 100
  })
  .add({
    targets: ".progress-bar",
    duration: 2000,
    width: 81,
    easing: "linear"
  })
  .add({
    targets: ".button",
    width: 0,
    duration: 1
  })
  .add({
    targets: ".progress-bar",
    width: 40,
    height: 39,
    delay: 500,
    duration: 750,
    borderRadius: 80,
    backgroundColor: "#71DFBE",
    left: 20
  })
  .add({
    targets: pathEl,
    strokeDashoffset: [offset, 0],
    duration: 200,
    easing: "easeInOutSine"
  });


$(".button").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  let validationOK = true;
  
  const form = document.forms.myform;
    let data = Object.fromEntries(new FormData(form).entries())
    for (let entrie in data) {
      if (!form[entrie].checkValidity()) {
        validationOK = false
        form[entrie].classList.add('shakingErr')
        setTimeout(() => {
          form[entrie].classList.remove('shakingErr')
        }, 820)
      }
    }
    
  if (validationOK) {
    basicTimeline.play();
    
    // submit action
    fetch(form.action, {
        method: form.method,
        body: JSON.stringify(data),
        headers: {
          Accept: 'application/json'
        }
      })
      .finally(() => {
        window.location = "thankyou.html"
      })
  }
});
```

```css
/* Contact Form */

input[type=text],
[type=email],
select,
textarea {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 12px;
  border: 1px solid #555;
  margin-top: 6px;
  margin-bottom: 16px;
  resize: vertical;
}

input[type="text"]:focus,
input[type="email"]:focus,
#subject:focus {
  background: var(--bgFormElsFocus);
  transform: scale(1.02);
  transition: transform 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

.contactform {
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 50px;
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
  padding: 5px;
  z-index: 2;
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-bottom: auto;
  margin-top: 1%;
  width: 100%;
  animation-name: gradient;
  animation-duration: 3s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

.contactform:hover {
  animation-name: gradient;
  animation-duration: 15s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

.column {
  float: center;
  width: 50%;
  margin-top: 6px;
  padding: 20px;
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .column,
  input[type=submit] {
    width: auto;
    margin-top: 0;
  }
}

form .shakingErr {
  border-color: red;
  animation: shake 0.82s forwards;
}

@keyframes shake {
  10%,
  90% {
    transform: translate3d(-1px, 0, 0);
  }
  20%,
  80% {
    transform: translate3d(2px, 0, 0);
  }
  30%,
  50%,
  70% {
    transform: translate3d(-4px, 0, 0);
  }
  40%,
  60% {
    transform: translate3d(4px, 0, 0);
  }
}


/* fancy button styles */

.buttonWrapper {
  height: 39px;
  width: 81px;
  position: relative;
}

.button {
  background: #2B2D2F;
  height: 39px;
  width: 81px;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  left: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 4px;
  z-index: 10;
}

.text {
  font: .8rem/1 poppins;
  color: #71DFBE;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-52%);
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.progress-bar {
  position: absolute;
  height: 20px;
  width: 0;
  left: 40px;
  top: 50%;
  border-radius: 200px;
  transform: translateY(-50%) translateX(-50%);
  background: black;
}

svg {
  width: 15px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 20px;
  transform: translateY(-50%) translateX(-8px);
}

.check {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #FFFFFF;
  stroke-width: 3;
  stroke-linecap: round;
  stroke-linejoin: round;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>replit</title>
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:600" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:600" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animejs/2.0.2/anime.js">
  </script>

</head>

<body>
  <!-- start contact section -->
  <section id="contact">
    <div class="container" data-aos="fade-up">
      <div class="contactform">
        <div style="text-align:center">
          <div class="section-title">
            <h2><br />Get In Touch</h2>
          </div>
          <p>Feel Free To Reach Out To Me Through This Form! </p>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="column">
            <form name="myform" action="https://formspree.io/f/xrg123232jbqpq" id="my-form" method="POST" novalidate>
              <label for="firstname">First Name</label>
              <input type="text" id="first name" name="firstname" required placeholder="Your First Name.." required>
              <label for="lastname">Last Name</label>
              <input type="text" id="lastname" name="lastname" placeholder="Your Last Name.." required>
              <label for="email">Email:</label>
              <input type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Your Email.." required>
              <label for="subject">Subject</label>
              <textarea id="subject" name="subject" placeholder="Lets Collaborate.." style="height:170px" required></textarea>
              <!-- <input type="submit" value="Submit"> -->
              <div class='buttonWrapper'>
                <button class="button" type="submit">
                  <div class="text">Submit</div>
                </button>
                <div class="progress-bar"></div>
                <svg x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 25 30" style="enable-background:new 0 0 25 30;">
                  <path class="check" class="st0" d="M2,19.2C5.9,23.6,9.4,28,9.4,28L23,2" />
                </svg>
              </div>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Update for the input's `border-color` don't get highlighted.

This is a CSS problem, the error CSS is being overridden by the default input style.

[image]

We can make the error style stronger by changing the selector like this.

```
form .shakingErr {
  border-color: red;
  animation: shake 0.82s forwards;
}
```

Comment: hey, there seems to be a very small issue. The top two fields dont get highlighted red when you click the submit button.

Comment: You're right, I saw that but it's not the main point in this question so I just ignored it. Anyway, I just updated my answer to fix the CSS problem.

Comment: Hey, can you help me with one small issue? When you click the submit button and the animation plays, you can see that when the checkmark logo goes towards the left, there is a small thing thats in the background of the logo. How can I remove that?